# writing the results of json to a csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm using DictWriter cause I thought it would be easier but I'm getting no where. I trying to write my json file to a csv file with each field in it's own column.

json file:

```
[ {"district": "4", 
"id": "DEL000027", 
"full_name": "Gerald L. Brady", "party": "Democratic", 
"email": "Gerald.Brady@state.de.us"}, 
{"district": "37", 
"id": "DEL000028", "full_name": "Ruth Briggs  King", 
"party": "Republican", 
"email": "Ruth.BriggsKing@state.de.us"}]
```

here is the script that I wrote:

```
import json, csv

mainFile = open("vote.json", "r")
data = json.load(mainFile)

with open('names.csv','w') as csvfile:
    values = ['full_name', 'party', 'district','email']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=values)

writer.writeheader()
for item in data:
    writer.writerows(item)<----- error but don't know why it's an error
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please fix your indentation. your code looks all right but for the indentation which could cause the file to be closed before it's written into.

Comment: The function is `writerows`, not `writero`.

Comment: please fix your indentation _better_. My crystal ball (no other way to guess) tells me that you're writing to the file _outside_ the `with` block: operation on closed file. Is Irma right?

Comment: yeah, sounds very much like it. Please post your error message. "getting nowhere" won't get you anywere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `writerow()` since you're iterating over the rows.

`writerows()` takes a list of lists (of rows)

```
import json, csv

mainFile = open("vote.json", "r")
data = json.load(mainFile)

with open('names.csv','w') as csvfile:
    values = ['full_name', 'party', 'district','email']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=values, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Alternatively, you could use `writerows()`

```
import json, csv

mainFile = open("vote.json", "r")
data = json.load(mainFile)

with open('names.csv','w') as csvfile:
    values = ['full_name', 'party', 'district','email']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=values, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I agree the question was not formatted correctly, but please write the `writerow` under th `with` clause. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function is called `writerows` (with an `s`). So the function does not expect a **single** dictionary, you need to pass **an iterable of dictionaries**, so you can write:

```
import json, csv

with open('names.csv','w') as csvfile:
    values = ['full_name', 'party', 'district','email']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=values, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerows(data)
```

You need to use the `extrasaction='ignore'` here since your dictionaries contain extra keys that are not present in the `values` list. The writer will error if you do not provide a way to resolve this.

You also need to write the data in the *body* of the `with` clause, since after the (end of the) `with`, the file is closed again.

This snippet produces:

```
full_name,party,district,email
Gerald L. Brady,Democratic,4,Gerald.Brady@state.de.us
Ruth Briggs  King,Republican,37,Ruth.BriggsKing@state.de.us
```